# Is it possible to subscribe a calendar from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Pretty sure it's not possible, but I cannot find a definitive answer.

Simply, I want to add a button to my iPhone app that subscribes the user to a relevant iCal feed.

---

I'm assuming since there's lack of documentation that this isn't possible, and that the best I can do is provide instructions and a link to copy and paste?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about .ics links, try something like this:

```
NSString *url = @"http://server/filename.ics";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

This shows an uialertview with the question to the user if he/she wants to subscribe.

Comment: Yes, it should definitely work. Are you using a valid ics website?
If it doesn't work, what's the OS version number you are testing it on?

Try for example the following URL:
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/caldata/EnglishHolidays.ics

Comment: I had trouble getting the alert to appear. Instead it showed a list of events that it wanted to add.

I changed the scheme name from http:// to webcal:// and was able to subscribe.

    NSString *url = @"webcal://server/filename.ics";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];